# How to use nested property to define unique key in cosmos DB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, unique-key, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have to define unique key constraints on cosmos document. Since document structure is not plain format instead of that it has nested json structure so syntax was how can i do that ?

This is what I am entering on azure portal :

/data.property1,/data.property2,/data.property3

getting error : 
{\"Errors\":[\"Error parsing the unique key path '\/data.property1' at position 7. Make sure the unique key path does not contain wildcards and invalid characters.\"]}

Cosmos DB document layout :

```
  "id": "4d9cd2c2-8ae7-40b9-a78e-7e8879935149",

  "SystemProperties": {
    "Device": "Device1"
  },
  "Scenario": {
    "Type": "Event"
  },
  "data": {
    "property1": "SLIC",
    "property2": "1.1",
    "property3": "1.1"}
}
```

Help me in case document is like this how can i use nested properties to define unique key ?

Answer (score 3):

Got the solution to do this :
/data/property1,/data/property2,/data/property3